# What would be the probability of 2 days less than 9 m/s?

Tags: probability

If for instance I am looking if for days with a wind speed less then 9 m/s and I find that in a particular month out of 300 days in the last 10 years there have been 45 days with wind speeds less than 9 m/s so a 15% of having a day with a wind speed less then 9 m/s. I then find looking at all the days with wind speeds less then 9 m/s there is 50% chance of the next day being less than 9 m/s. How would I calculate what the chances of having 2 days with wind speeds less then 9 m/s? with them being in my view dependant it's not a simple addition

Cheers

Comment: Even if it is tractable, I doubt the equation would fit a screen or two. The day-2 probability being correlated with day-1 comes from an unobserved common cause. To get something principled, you'd need to fit some climate model to historical data, then calculate the likelihood for the future events under that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are asking is given I do not know the wind speed of the day before, what is the probability that the next 2 days have wind speeds below 9m/s (which is akin to the equilibrium frequency of the event) - then the answer is simply $$P(\text{2 consecutive days of } WS < 9) = P(WS_t<9|WS_{t-1}  \text{ unkown}) \times P(WS_{t+1}<9|WS_t<9)$$ which is $0.15 * 0.5 = 0.075$ according to the probabilities you have specified above.